# Is it a coincidence that the maximum number of protons in a stable nucleus is on the order of $\alpha_s / \alpha_{EM}$?

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chromodynamics, physical-constants

The equivalent to the fine-structure constant for the strong interaction is about $\alpha_s \approx 0.5$ at the proton rest mass energy (and it runs pretty slowly with energy, so it's on this order for any energy on the order of the parton mass). The fine structure constant is a little bigger than $1/137$ at this energy scale. Therefore, in an extremely rough sense, we can maybe say that the strong-interaction attraction between protons is around 70 times stronger than the electrostatic repulsion.

The maximum number of protons in a stable nucleus (82 plus a comparable number of neutrons, in several isotopes of lead), is on the same order of magnitude. If we believe our rough story that the electrostatic repulsion is about 70 times weaker than the strong attraction at nuclear energy scales, then we could go on to argue that it therefore takes about 80 protons to build up enough electrostatic repulsion to overcome the strong attraction and destabilize the nucleus.

Is there any truth at all to this simple story, or this just a coincidence? Nuclear stability is an incredibly complicated subject, and obviously this explanation could at best only possibly provide a very rough rule of thumb and not a precise prediction. Does it even do that? Put another way, if we imagine cranking the electromagnetic fine-structure constant down to, say, $10^{-3}$ while leaving the strong coupling constant unchanged, would we expect nuclei with up to about a thousand protons to become stable? Or is the upper threshold for nuclear stability determined primarily by the value of the strong coupling constant and not the electromagnetic fine-structure constant?

Comment: FWIW: there are lots of heuristic arguments as to why $1/\alpha$ is an approximate upper bound on the number of nucleons in an stable atom (see e.g. [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228183/84967)). For example, this is the limit where the Coulomb electric field generated by the protons is of order of the [Schwinger limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit). It is a very old problem and, to the best of my knowledge, nobody has been able to make it work in a convincing way.