# Maximum Electron Speed Around an Atomic Nucleus

Tags: particle-physics, electrons

At what element do we hit a wall because of the electrons relativistic speed?  i.e. the speed of the outer shells can go no faster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this a correct demonstration for why elements above untriseptium cannot exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228183/is-this-a-correct-demonstration-for-why-elements-above-untriseptium-cannot-exist)

Comment: *the speed of the outer shells can go no faster* The *inner* electrons have higher kinetic energy than the outer ones.

Comment: Thanks @G.Smith.  I had that backwards

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac equation has no one electron ground state for Z>
137. This is assuming a point charge nucleus. For an extended nucleus the maximum Z goes up to around 180. In some textbooks it is assumed that such nuclei are instable against e-p pair creation where the electron is somehow captured by the nucleus and lowers its charge to below the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Atoms and their electrons are in the quantum mechanical regime. Quantum mechanics is deterministic only on probability distributions, one cannot talk of speeds of electrons around the nucleus because there are no orbits, [just orbitals,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) probability loci where the electrons can be found with a given energy momentum vector.

One electron in a specific orbital will have an energy-momentum vector. That momentum divided by the mass of the electron will be in units of velocity, but it is the available energy levels from the solution of the equations that are giving limits, not the nominal velocities. (see the answer by my2cts.