# Theoretically maximum atomic number and its stability?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radiation, half-life

Is there a theoretical maximum to the atomic number? Is it possible to reach $Z = 150$ or $Z = 200$? I am not really asking about our experimental, but theoretical limitations that possibly prevent us reaching extremely high atomic numbers. It seems to me that there is nothing that's stopping us from reaching these high atomic numbers if we accept that we will be working with ridiculously short life-times.

Also, the additional thing I'm interested about is the stability of such atoms. What is the **theoretical** maximum atomic number for a stable atom? Contrary to the previous question, here I'm almost certain that such maximum does indeed exist. Since the nuclear force is short-ranged it is intuitively clear that large atoms will decay into smaller chunks.

I do know that these questions can be analyzed from the point of view of liquid drop model, but it is questionable how well does that model describe the physical situation that is experimentally unreachable.

Comment: Kind of related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/228183/123208

Comment: It depends a lot on what you understand by 'stable'. From about $Z=92$ elements begin to show spontaneous decay. It tends to get worse as $Z$ increases. Have you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability